# nginx+gunicorn+django/mezzanine not serving static files

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a mezzanine app. I am using gunicorn as the webserver and nginx as a reverse proxy. However, static files are not being served (however, they are served via the built-in django development server). I have run python manage.py collectstatic.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {

        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        # ..
        # .

    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {

        # Running port
        listen 80;

        # Settings to serve static files 
        location ^~ /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            root /root/myapp/myapp/static/;

        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico)
        # outside /static directory
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;

        }

        # Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location / {

            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to serve static files?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an incorrect use of `root` vs `alias` in nginx.  assuming in your settings.py file you have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

then you want a location that looks like:

```
    location /static/  {
        # Example:
        # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
        root /root/myapp/myapp/;
        # - or -
        # alias /root/myapp/myapp/static/;
    }
```

For [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

> Defines a replacement for the specified location. For example, with the following configuration
>
> ```
>    location /i/ {
>        alias /data/w3/images/;
>    }
> ```
>
> on request of “/i/top.gif”, the file /data/w3/images/top.gif will be sent. 
>   ...
>   When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
>  location /images/ {
>    alias /data/w3/images/;
>  }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the root directive instead:
>
> ```
>  location /images/ {
>    root /data/w3;
>  }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Should I try it with alias? It seems you suggest I should use root instead, but I never used alias, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Check out the difference between my root directive and yours.  You can use either root or alias, you just have to make sure that you are pointing to the right directory.

Comment: Ok, I tried both (dropping the 'static' directory with the root directive, and keeping it with 'alias'). Neither worked. The static resources are returning a 403.

Comment: You’re getting a 403?  What’s the error in the access log file?

Comment: "CLIENT IP" [18/Jan/2017:22:08:38 +0000] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 403 178 "SITE IP"  "USER AGENT"

Comment: Is it possible that this problem is arising because I am running all my nginx/gunicorn/django commands as root?

Comment: It shouldn't for nginx because nginx usually runs its worker processes as the nginx user (or ww-data n ubuntu). There's usually a user setting in the main nginx.conf that controls that user (also sometimes in the systemd unit).  A user permission is what I was thinking it might be as well.  Whichever user (www-data, nginx or other) that the nginx process is running on, you will want to make sure that it has access to read and execute on all folders up the path to static.